# The name patientid does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Hi I get this error message "the name patientid does not exist in the current context" and also, "the name formpatientid does not exist in the current context". Why would this be occuring?

```
    public void patientUpdate()
    {
        hospitalSQLEntities db = new hospitalSQLEntities();
        string formpatiendid = Request.Params["patientid"];
        patient mypatient = null;
        try
        {
            mypatient = db.patients.Single(u => **patientid.Equals(formpatientid))**;
        }
```

Comment: did correcting the spelling solve your issue?

Comment: all solved! and Enigmativity helped by adding the u.patientid.Equals. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this fix the issue?

```
   public void patientUpdate()
    {
        hospitalSQLEntities db = new hospitalSQLEntities();
        string formpatientid = Request.Params["patientid"];
        patient mypatient = null;
        try
        {
            mypatient = db.patients.Single(u =>
                u.patientid.Equals(formpatientid));
        }
```

I also not use the `try` block. It's bad practice to just trap everything.

Comment: In this case wrapping it in a Try block might a good idea since the Single method will throw an InvalidOperationException if there is no patient with the specified Id. However in that case you're verging on using exceptions to control program flow so it might be a better idea still to adopt the tester-doer pattern :)

Comment: @MattDavey - Use `SingleOrDefault` rather than `Single` if there might not be a result.

Comment: then you're likely just swapping an InvalidOperationException for a NullReferenceException instead... tester-doer would be the better option (if db.patients.Any(xxx)) then db.patients.First(xxx)..

Comment: @MattDavey - The OP hasn't give us enough code to see if she handles nulls or not. And since we don't see the rest of the code the "tester-doer" approach is equally likely to cause a `NullReferenceException`. Also, by calling `Any` and then `First` you are issuing two database calls. By using `FirstOrDefault` you are only doing one call.